# How do I tell Windows 10 to automatically move windows onto the main screen when I disconnect my monitor?

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have a Windows 10 laptop that I use at home and work. At both places I have a monitor that I connect to, and I have several windows on both my main screen and my monitor screen when I disconnect the monitor.

In the past, I have noticed that all my windows automatically migrate to the main screen when I disconnect. But lately, I have been having trouble with my Windows 10 laptop thinking it's still connected to a monitor even when it's not. It keeps my windows on the second screen even though there is no second screen.

How do I tell Windows 10 to move my windows automatically to the main screen from the second screen when I disconnect the monitor?

Answer (score 1):

For moving individual windows, select the program in the taskbar or alt+tab to it. When it is selected hit the key combo [Windows]+[Shift]+[RightArrow] (or [LeftArrow] depending on which side the monitor is usually on) a few times to get it to arrive at the correct screen.

I'm not at my machine to try it, but you can also try Hitting [Windows]+P (and hold the Windows key to continue selecting the mode) to change between Extend mode and Disconnect Projector.